# Algorithm for checking if a polyhedron is bounded.

Tags: geometry, algorithms, polyhedra, polytopes, discrete-geometry

Given a polyhedron in the form $Ax \leq b$, I need to know a way to determine if the polyhedron is bounded.

I need an algorithm for which given a matrix $A$ and a vector $b$ as input, 
it should output True if the polyhedron thus formed is bounded, otherwise output False.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A naive (but deterministic) algorithm is to check if the [support function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_function) of the polyhedron is bounded for each of the $2n$ canonical basis directions $\pm e_i$, for $i = 1, \ldots, n$. In the worst case this requires solving $2n$ linear programs.

I'm aware of a better approach that uses Stiemke's theorem of alternatives, which requires just 1 LP:

**Proposition 1.** If $\ker(A) \neq \{ 0\}$ => $P$ is unbounded.

**Proposition 2.** Assume that $\ker(A) = \{0\}$ and $P$ is non-empty. Then $P$ is bounded if and only if the following linear program admits a feasible solution: $\min \Vert y \Vert_1$ subject to $A^T y = 0$ and $y \geq 1$.

---

The naive method is available in the [Julia](https://julialang.org/) library [LazySets.jl](https://github.com/JuliaReach/LazySets.jl) (which i'm coauthor) and you can use it as `isbounded(P)` where `P` is the polyhedron. The second method is waiting to be implemented :) -- see [LazySets#1136](https://github.com/JuliaReach/LazySets.jl/issues/1136).

EDIT: the method in question is now available since LazySets release [v1.37.4](https://github.com/JuliaReach/LazySets.jl/releases/tag/v1.37.4).

Comment: If possible, can you provide a link of the code in your repo where the naive way is implemented ?

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/JuliaReach/LazySets.jl/blob/master/src/Interfaces/LazySet.jl#L290), which relies on `ρ(d, S)` for the given set $S$. For a polyhedron in half-space representation (`HPolyhedron`) that's implemented [here](https://github.com/JuliaReach/LazySets.jl/blob/master/src/Sets/HPolyhedron.jl#L88).

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

Linear programming is (in practice, with readily available software) fast.  Take a random unit vector $c$ and maximize and minimize $c \cdot x$ subject to $A x \le b$.  If the polyhedron is nonempty and bounded, both problems will have optimal solutions.
If it is unbounded, then with probability $1$ one or both problems will be unbounded.

Comment: Consider a $[-1,1]^3$ cube with one of its faces removed (let removed face be x=1) as the polyhedron to check, and let $c$ vector be (0,0,1). The maximum and minimum value of $c.x$ will be -1 and 1 respectively even

Comment: Did you notice I wrote "random"?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I noticed random but didn't focus on your last line that says with probability 1. The case I mentioned has a finite but low probability, thus repeating it for few $c$ vectors will do. Right ?

Comment: Yes. In principle (if the entries are real numbers) the probability of $c_1 = 0$ would be $0$.  If you use finite precision, the probability will be nonzero, but very small.  Yes, if you repeat a few times independently, the probability becomes very very small.  Of course, with finite precision there are other numerical issues that must be addressed, e.g. you can't really tell whether a computed number is $0$ or very slightly positive or negative.

Comment: Thanks for the help.